# How to add custom ColorFunction in FillingStyle with Opacity

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot a series of lines with one half-space filled for each line. By setting opacity to something less than 1, I want to make the overlaps stand out. What I have looks something like this:

```
Plot[Table[x + a, {a, 0, 5}], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y < 5],
 Filling -> 5, FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.25]]]
```

[image]

This is fine. Now I want to also shade the colors for each half space in a particular way. Instead of the flat shading for each at present, say I want to shade it by the `y` value. I.e., if the flat shade color is blue, the shade of blue is scaled by `y` (0 most intense or 5 most intense doesn't matter). So at the first overlap, it automatically becomes `2y`, `3y` when two half-spaces overlay.

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `Plot`. It does take a ColorFunction as option but that uses a fixed color for each vertical line. It looks like you should use Graphics primitives like `Polygon` and `VertexColors`.

Comment: I am having trouble visualizing what you want.  Is Heike's solution correct?  If not, how is it incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `ParametricPlot`. For example

```
ParametricPlot[
 Table[{s, i + s/2 + t}, {i, 0, 2}], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 3}, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 3}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, s, t}, 
   Directive[Opacity[0.2], ColorData["NeonColors"][y/3]]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

**Result:**

[image: Overlapping regions]